# Getting text from <span> tag element

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have a table in which each row has a xpath and within each row a column is embedded. There is a  tag in row's xpath that changes text based on what you choose on that page.

```
<div class='xyz'>
  <span> some text </span>
</div>
```

I am doing `//div[@class='xyz']/span.text()`

However, I am not able to get the text from here.

I am using python with VSCode.

Comment: This is not a valid syntax `//div[@class='xyz']/span.text()`. You need to use `//div[@class='xyz']/span/text()` or just use this `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='xyz']/span").text`

Answer (score 2):

The syntax to get the text from span tag using *xpath* is incorrect.

This is the proper *xpath*,

```
//div[@class='xyz']/span/text()
```

Or you can use `.text` with web driver `find_element_by_xpath` to extract text.

```
span_text = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='xyz']/span").text
```

If `/span` is the only child element of `//div[@class='xyz']` then you can use this path instead of the one above `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='xyz']").text`

You can read about how to use xpath with selenium webdriver [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-by-xpath).

Comment: Thank you, I am certainly using "span_text = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='xyz']/span").text" but its not getting it.

Comment: @Aboyhasnoname Can i have the website address which you are scraping ?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `xpath` the bellow :

```
get_text = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="xyz"]').text
print get_text
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract the text **some text** from the desired element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.xyz>span"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='xyz']/span"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```